# Hide nav in ASP.NET page After Login

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, asp.net

i just work on my first web APP with ASP.NET

[image]

So, i have the top nav (red arrow ) in all my web app, how can i hide from specific pages?
I want that user will see only the side nav (purple arrow ).

Maybe i need to do something in the controller ? or in my _Layout.cshtml ?

This is the code of this page:

```
@{
    /**/

    ViewBag.Title = "AfterLogin";
}
<link href="~/Content/SidebarMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/TOdo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/todo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<h2>To Do App</h2>

@if (Session["UserID"] != null)
{

    <div>
        Welcome : <a href="#"> @Session["UserName"] </a><br />
        <a href="/Register/Logout"> Logout</a>
    </div>


    <html>
    <head>

    </head>


    <body>
        <div class="area"></div><nav class="main-menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://justinfarrow.com">
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Dashboard
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </li>
                <li class="has-subnav">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Stars Components
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </li>
                <li class="has-subnav">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Forms
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </li>
                <li class="has-subnav">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-folder-open fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Pages
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Graphs and Statistics
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-font fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Quotes
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-table fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Tables
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Maps
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-info fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Documentation
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="logout">
                <li>
                    <a href="/Register/Logout">
                        <i class="fa fa-power-off fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Logout
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>




        <body>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h1>To-Do <small>List</small></h1>
                <form role="form">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Task" name="task">
                </form>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn btn-primary">Add</button>
            </div>
            <div></div>
            <ul class="list-unstyled" id="todo"></ul>
        </body>







</html>



}
```

AND this is the _Layout.cshtml code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Underlying Layout.cshtml will not render nav when a user is logged in. Notice this line: '@if(!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)'

```
                <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
                @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
                @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
                @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

            </head>
            <body>
                @if(!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) 
                {
                    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
                <div class="container body-content">
                    @RenderBody()
                    <hr />
                    <footer>
                        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
                    </footer>
                </div>

                @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
                @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
                @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: You could copy-paste the if statement what you used for rendering the username again around the nav element, but now check if session is null:
@if (Session["UserID"] == null)